# how to fetch data from nested Dictionary in C# code

Tags: c#, dictionary, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to fetch data from nested Dictionary in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801905/how-to-fetch-data-from-nested-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

I need to fetch data from nested Dictionary **IN C#**. My Dictionary is like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<ulong, string>> allOffset = 
  new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<ulong, string>>();
```

I need to fetch all keys/values of the full dictionary, represented like so:

```
string->>ulong, string
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "->>"? Your question isn't very clear - please give an example with concrete data, just missing the bit of logic you want, and it's probably going to be easy. It would also help if you'd say which version of .NET you're using, so we know whether or not to use LINQ :)

Comment: If you didn't get the answer you wanted from your initial question, try clarifying your requirements, instead of asking it again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801905/how-to-fetch-data-from-nested-dictionary-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to do it:

```
var flatKeysAndValues =
    from outer in allOffset    // Iterates over the outer dictionary
    from inner in outer.Value  // Iterates over each inner dictionary
    select new
               {
                   NewKey = outer.Key + "->>" + inner.Key,
                   NewValue = inner.Value
               };
```

Example of usage:

```
foreach (var flatKeysAndValue in flatKeysAndValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NewKey: {0} | NewValue: {1}", 
                             flatKeysAndValue.NewKey, flatKeysAndValue.NewValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if you want to write the data to the console, or want to transform it into a new object structure.

But in case you just want to print, give this a try:

```
foreach( var pair in allOffset )
{
  foreach( var innerPair in pair.Value )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}->>{1},{2}", pair.Key, innerPair.Key, innerPair.Value);
  }
}
```